# Can I access Electron's HTML/CSS via app.asar?

Tags: testing, windows-10, electron, asar

I'm testing a desktop app being built in [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/). Since the app’s layout is CSS/HTML based, I was hoping to do simple layout modifications without access to the source material. Even if I can't see my mods in the running app, it would be useful to extract HTML/CSS/JavaScript templates, modify these and see the results in a browser.

**Question 1:** Is the above possible?

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30167226/how-to-protect-source-code-in-electron-project) question I'm assuming `app.asar` could be what I'm looking for, but being on Windows 10, it seems that installing [asar](https://github.com/electron/asar) (and Node, NPM, Python and Visual Studio) just to unarchive files is [discouraged](https://github.com/electron/asar/issues/20).

**Question 2:** Can I access the files presumed to be inside `app.asar` without installing all the stuff mentioned above?

Comment: Sorry for necroing. I just wanted to say that there is now a 7-Zip plugin for opening asar files.

Comment: @HackerFinn Post as answer and I can flag as answered? :-)